# Form values are null in post request in play framework

Tags: java, forms, jsp, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have html to post back a form, like this:

```
@(message: String)

@main("Contact") {
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/contact.css")">
<div id="pageContainer">
    <div id="form">
        <div id="topText">
            <p>Have a question or need some assistance? Let us know and we'll get back to you ASAP.</p>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <form method="POST" action="@routes.Home.contact()">

            <div id="contactInfo">
                <label class="contactLabel">First Name:</label><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="contactInput" /> <br />
                <label class="contactLabel">Last Name:</label><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="contactInput" /> <br />
                <label class="contactLabel">Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" firstName" class="contactInput" /> <br />
                <label class="contactLabel">Company:</label><input type="text" id="company" name="company" class="contactInput" /> <br />
                <input type="hidden" id="hidden" name = "hidden"></input>
                <p id="crap">@message</p>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div id="message">
                <label class="contactLabel">Message:</label><textarea cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></input>
            </form>
    </div>

</div>

}
```

Back in the controller, it looks like this:

```
public static Result contact()
{

    //Map<String,String[]> values = request().body();
    DynamicForm form = form().bindFromRequest();
    String first = "";
    if(form.data().get("firstName") != null)
    first = form.data().get("firstName").toString();

    return ok(views.html.contact.render(first));
}
```

But when I look through the result of `form().bindFromRequest()`, it is always empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you pass directly the parameters `String hello, String hello1, String hello2` to your `Home.contact` method instead of retrieving them with `bindFromRequest`?

Comment: Besides, are you sure you are correctly using `firstName` both in controller and view?

Comment: @Alex apparently not.. is there anything special and specific to play that I need to do? Even when I tried passing them directly, it isn't sending them correctly. I get a "not enough arguments" error.

Comment: Can you show the real html/scala template and not something that looks like having input text with name=`hello`. Please show the real one, and the code of the `Home.contact` method including definition.

Comment: @alex edited with actual code

Comment: @alex if you can figure out what's going wrong with this by today, I'll put a 100 rep bounty on the question and give it to you when it's eligible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I would do that:

**template**

```
@(message: String, contactForm: Form[Contact])

@import helper._

@main("Contact") {
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/contact.css")">
<div id="pageContainer">
    <div id="form">
        <div id="topText">
            <p>Have a question or need some assistance? Let us know and we'll get back to you ASAP.</p>
        </div>
        <br/>
        @form(routes.Home.contact()) {
            <div id="contactInfo">
                <label class="contactLabel">First Name:</label> @inputText(contactForm("firstName"), 'class -> "contactInput"') <br />
                <label class="contactLabel">Last Name:</label> @inputText(contactForm("lastName"), 'class -> "contactInput"') <br />
                <label class="contactLabel">Email:</label> @inputText(contactForm("email"), 'class -> "contactInput"') <br />
                <label class="contactLabel">Company:</label> @inputText(contactForm("company"), 'class -> "contactInput"') <br />
                <input type="hidden" id="hidden" name="hidden"></input>
                <p id="crap">@message</p>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div id="message">
                <label class="contactLabel">Message:</label><textarea cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        }
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Class Contact**

```
public class Contact {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String email;
    public String company;
    // other stuff
}
```

**Controller**

```
public static Result contact() {
    Form<Contact> contactForm = form(Contact.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (contactForm.hasErrors()) {
        // process
    } else {
        // contactForm.get().firstName should be filled with the correct data
        return ok(views.html.contact.render("message", contactForm)); 
    }
}
```

Does it work for you ?
You should take a look at the Play2 documentation about these topics:

1. [JavaForms](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaForms)
2. [JavaForm Helpers](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaFormHelpers)

**Edit**

> if you can explain why the way I was doing it previously *didn't* work

I'm not sure about that, but I can see one problem in your code, you don't have to call `data()` on the dynamic form, using directly `DynamicForm.get()` is sufficient, so `first = form.get("firstName")` is sufficient.

Besides as you can see from the [DynamicForm Javadoc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/data/DynamicForm.html#get%28java.lang.String%29)

> get(java.lang.String key)
>
> Gets the concrete value **if the submission was a success**.

The internal map behind `DynamicForm` has values if there is no errors, so you may check with `hasErrors` before actually getting concrete values from field.

From my point of view, it is better and easier to use the `form(Contact.class).bindFromRequest()` style that will fill an instance of class `Contact`, this without saying that fields can be validated using Java annotations.

Comment: It worked. Bonus points if you can explain why the way I was doing it previously *didn't* work

Comment: taking away your accepted status so that I can give you your bounty later on

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a `Request` to `bindFromRequest()` method. For example

```
 DynamicForm form = form().bindFromRequest(request());
```

The `request` function provides the current `Request` for the current action.
Seems like `bindFromRequest` doesn't bind automatically the current Request

I was having the same problem and google brought me here, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly the same problem but on my Windows developing Play 2.6 app I had similar issue. Binding did not work. I mean the Form's data field had proper values, but the values of model were empty. That was causing No such element exception: No value present. I've spent quite a while looking into this. What fixed the issue was cleaning project, recompiling and running it again. Ehh.