# NullPointerException when trying to save my Form

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new to PlayFramework and I'm following a video course on Udemy. However, their version from Play is 2.3.9, and I'm trying to do it with the version 2.5.4;

When I try to save my form, it gives me the following error:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:21)
    at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:18)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.avaje.ebean.Model.save(Model.java:208)
    at controllers.Services.save(Services.java:28)
    at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Routes.scala:227)
    at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Routes.scala:227)
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:157)
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:156)
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:136)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:73)
    at play.http.HttpRequestHandler$1.call(HttpRequestHandler.java:54)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:108)
```

My form:

```
@(serviceForm : Form[Service])
@import helper._


@main("Service info"){
  <h1>Service Information</h1>
  @helper.form(action = routes.Services.save()){
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Service</legend>
      @helper.inputText(serviceForm.field("code"), '_label -> "Code")
      @helper.inputText(serviceForm.field("description"), '_label -> "Description")
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
  }
}
```

My model:

```
@Entity
public class Service extends Model {
    @Id
    public String code;
    public String description;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
public class Services extends Controller {

    @Inject FormFactory formFactory;

    public Result list(){
        return TODO;
    }

    public Result addService(){
        Form<Service> serviceForm = formFactory.form(Service.class);
        return ok(info.render(serviceForm));
    }

    public Result save(){
        Form<Service> serviceForm = formFactory.form(Service.class);
        Service service = serviceForm.bindFromRequest().get();
        service.save();

        return  redirect(routes.Services.addService());
    }
}
```

I really don't know where to go from here. And there's not many posts on Google talking about this. Any help would be great!

**EDIT**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does `serviceForm.bindFromRequest().get();` return a non null value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might have the same, or related, problem. [Please check my new post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263538/why-play-uses-old-ebean-version-in-new-project-templates). Basically, my problem was with Ebean plugin version.

Also, you can see my changes on my repository [here](https://bitbucket.org/valterhenrique/consulting-services-inc/commits/113da6af237914a19f1393edd6dea08c363ab0eb).

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

[Issue with bindFromRequest in Play! Framework 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365707/issue-with-bindfromrequest-in-play-framework-2-3)

> I have been struggling with exactly the same problem: bindFromRequest
>   returned nulls for "name" field. I did exactly the same what a guy in
>   this Play for Java introduction video did:
>   youtube.com/watch?v=bLrmnjPQsZc . But still no luck. I've been working
>   on Windows 7 with JDK 1.8. IDE: Eclipse 4.4.0. And I run activator
>   through cygwin.
>
> This is what solved the problem for me:
>
> In Eclipse: Project -> Build Automatically - > turn off In cygwin:
>   ./activator clean; ./activator compile; ./activator run; After this,
>   bindFromRequest binds name correctly and puts it into the database.

Comment: No, still the same error. Thanks for tip anyway! :)