# Why Play Framework uses old Ebean version in the new project templates?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, ebean

I was bashing my head to the wall (almost literally) trying to figure out why I was having this [NullPointException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940149/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-save-my-form) problem for the past **17 days** (now you believe, don't you ?).

So, reading and reading through Play's Documentation I have noticed something ( that I don't know how I haven't noticed before! ).

*Configuring Ebean
Play comes with the Ebean ORM. To enable it, add the Play Ebean plugin to your SBT plugins in project/plugins.sbt:*

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")
```

Also, reading some posts at [Play's forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-framework), I have noticed that version `2.5.6` was released, and I was using version `2.5.4`, in any case I upgrade it both and it worked, it solved my `NullPointerException` problem.

However, I have created a new project via Play's template:

```
activator new

Fetching the latest list of templates...

Browse the list of templates: http://lightbend.com/activator/templates
Choose from these featured templates or enter a template name:
  1) minimal-akka-java-seed
  2) minimal-akka-scala-seed
  3) minimal-java
  4) minimal-scala
  5) play-java
  6) play-scala
(hit tab to see a list of all templates)
> 5
Enter a name for your application (just press enter for 'play-java')
> a-new-project
OK, application "a-new-project" is being created using the "play-java" template.

To run "a-new-project" from the command line, "cd a-new-project" then:
/tmp/000/a-new-project/activator run

To run the test for "a-new-project" from the command line, "cd a-new-project" then:
/tmp/000/a-new-project/activator test

To run the Activator UI for "a-new-project" from the command line, "cd a-new-project" then:
/tmp/000/a-new-project/activator ui
```

Then checking `project/plugins.sbt` file:

```
// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(PlayEbean).
// addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

Which leads to my question: if you're starting a new project, via play's project template, why would you start with the oldest version of a plugin ? It would be better to start with the latest version of these plugins ?

You can see my changes on my repository [here](https://bitbucket.org/valterhenrique/consulting-services-inc/commits/113da6af237914a19f1393edd6dea08c363ab0eb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a big deal. It is just that the template got outdated. The `play-java` template is defined here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/templates/play-java

And, you can see that the template is adding play-ebean plugin here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/templates/play-java/project/plugins.sbt#L21

Unfortunately, the `EBEAN_VERSION` variable was not updated, as you can see here:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/templates/build.sbt#L62

If you want, you can submit a (very small and specific) pull request to fix this.

### Edit:

This pull request updates templates plugins: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/6515

Comment: There is also a working ebean example here: https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean-example

Comment: Great Marcos! I'm glad to help :)